# Insert a QSqlRecord of type serial in PostgreSQL

Tags: c++, postgresql, qt, qt5, qsqldatabase

I'm working with the [Books](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-books-example.html) Qt example but instead of SQLite I'm using PostgreSQL, so my main table and related tables were created with the following code:

```
QSqlQuery q;
if (!q.exec(QLatin1String("create table orders(id serial primary key, name varchar, supplier integer, product integer, year integer, rating integer)")))
    return q.lastError();
if (!q.exec(QLatin1String("create table suppliers(id serial primary key, name varchar, birthdate date)")))
    return q.lastError();
if (!q.exec(QLatin1String("create table products(id serial primary key, name varchar)")))
    return q.lastError();
```

Now, I want to add a new row into the database. I have the next code so far:

```
QSqlRecord record;

QSqlField f0("id", QVariant::Int);
QSqlField f1("name", QVariant::String);
QSqlField f2("supplier", QVariant::Int);
QSqlField f3("product", QVariant::Int);
QSqlField f4("year", QVariant::Int);
QSqlField f5("rating", QVariant::Int);

// id is serial and I'd like not to set manually the value
f0.setValue(100);
f1.setValue(QVariant("Test1"));
f2.setValue(QVariant(3));
f3.setValue(QVariant(3));
f4.setValue(QVariant(2001));
f5.setValue(QVariant(5));

record.append(f0);
record.append(f1);
record.append(f2);
record.append(f3);
record.append(f4);
record.append(f5);

model->insertRecord(-1, record)
```

And here we have the problem. As you can see, `id` is the primary key and its type is `serial`. If I don't set the value (i.e. removing the line `record.append(f0);`), the table is properly updated in PostgreSQL but Qt shows a blank row in the `TableView` we have in the `MainWindow`.

I've tried with `QSqlField::setAutoValue` and `QSqlField::setGenerated` but the behavior is the same. `QAbstractItemModel::setData` would be another option, but it's not a solution, either.

I could insert the record and update after that the first field to the `id` stored in the database, but I'm wondering if this issue is a bug or the API is right and the problem is the way I'm using it.